# Why does adding any arbitrary RewriteRule cause the whole site to fail?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I'm using WordPress and this works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

However if I add this before the last line:

```
RewriteRule "^/iwillnevergetmatched$" "/testfoo" [R=301]
```

Then in my logs:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://example.org/foo

Comment: It's not failing due to an "arbitrary Rewrite Rule". It's failing due to too many redirects. Fix your rewrite rules and the issue will go away.

Comment: @EEAA Indeed, I can read the error message I quoted. What I'm saying is that the RewriteRule I've added doesn't match the URL. That's why I named it `iwillnevergetmatched`. **why** is it redirecting when it doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you're splitting an existing RewriteRule from its preceding conditions. This makes it unconditional, and it loops.